# How to detect PushNotificationIOS state after disabled manually on iPhone settings on React Native?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, permissions

after disable the push notification manually on phone settings，the code not triggered

```
PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('register', (deviceToken) => {
    console.log('PushNotificationIOS.register,-------', deviceToken);
        });

PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('registrationError', (response) => {
            console.log('PushNotificationIOS.registrationError,=====', response);
        });
```

so i couldn't detect whether the remote notification was disabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [checkpermissions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios#checkpermissions) from PushNotificationIOS, it returns an object like this:

```
{"alert":1,"badge":1,"sound":1}
```